# How to isolate Eclipse workspace from git local repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, egit

I installed EGit on Juno and created a Java project in workspace of Eclipse. Then I shared that project to Git. Then when I check the project's properties, I found that the project had been moved from its original workspace into Git local repository. When I make some changes in Eclipse editor, the changes are made on the local repository without commit.

How to isolate Eclipse workspace from git local repository?

(Well, my Eclipse workspace is ~/Documents/workspace, my git local repository is ~/git/myrepository1. )

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workspace is still in its original location outside of edit.  It's the projects that have been moved into the git-controlled directories.  Normally projects are created in the Eclipse workspace folder but you can override that default.

If you really want to isolate changes from git, you'll have to break git's control of the project, but you may still have to move the project contents back into your workspace.  Unfortunately, the process of getting further changes back into git gets really messy.

I've found it unnerving at first the way git controls my eclipse projects, but after a while it does begin to make sense and is really a very powerful version control function.

Comment: Are you saying that the OP's question is just a natural thing in git? I'm a newbie in git and that is not my idea of local repository.