# Confused about Git (EGit) - Project in workspace is the same with project in local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I am currently developing a project and I decided to use Git for my version control. I came accross this confusion.

Here is what I did. Assuming I already installed EGit in my Eclipse.

1. I created a new Java project.
2. Right click > Team > Share Project... > Git
3. I specified my local repository name and it's location. The location is outside my workspace folder. Then Finish.

When I look at the Git Repositories View, in the Working Directory, I can see that the local repository is successfully created.

Now, when I modify a file in my workspace, I can see that the file in the repository is also modified WITHOUT commiting it. Why is that? Is it normal in Git?

I did my homework and google this problem then I saw this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183548/how-to-isolate-eclipse-workspace-from-git-local-repository). I think my problem is the same. But the answer accepted did not satisfy my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand from the question, you are confused not about EGit and how it integrates Git into Eclipse, but about Git itself.

Git repository is managed right in your working directory. Repository itself resides, by default, in '.git/' directory. When you modify a file in your workspace you are only modifying it in the working directory. You can open 'Git Staging' view to see that git have noticed your changes, but they are not checked in yet.

I suggest you walk through this github's interactive tutorial. http://try.github.com/

Comment: So maybe they are right - the hardest thing about learning git is unlearning from other version controls (I'm from SVN)